# Appsrcipt :: MoveTo() function behaviour regarding permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

Since i can not find any documentation on this. Does moveto() function always inherit permissions of the parent folder  it was moved ro for the file itself?

Why im asking is, i have a script where moveTo() moves files uploaded by a google form to a shared folder. Me and other 5 ppl + owner have edit permissions to this Folder.  For some reason if the script has to move files i did upload (files where only i have permission to edit before i did upload them), the other 5 will get permissions to the file in the folder it was move to, but not me (despite me being the only one having permissions before moveto). On the other hand, if ANYone else upload files i would and also the other 5 ppl. get permissions to this file. So it seems it only omits permissions to files i do upload and only to myself , which makes little sense.
Does anyone know a explanation for this behaviour?

Is there an easy way to autoinherit permissions to files after moveto from parentfolder, or would this have to be done manually be extraction permissions into array and applying to the file..

Comment: To further clarify the matter, could you share these specific details: 1.) Who is the owner/creator of the Google Forms where you upload your files? 2.) Has this behavior been occurring since the beginning?

Comment: Script was done by me, one someoneelse account as her deployment and her trigger (on a folder i have editor,but she is owner/creator). Files are uploaded to the default upload form folder and moved with the sript after onformsubmit. I  tested with 10 different ppl using the form, and there are no issues that i can access their files. Only by accident i found that i actually cant see mine, because formerly i tested my form on my account. But as i said for ownership i did one from scratch on her account. Can you confirm that moveto() inherits perm, because this also seems incosistent in testing

Comment: In my testing, It seems that any files moved to a shared folder inherit the permissions of that folder. If this issue is inconsistent, you may want to consider reporting this behavior to the [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports).